# reading multiple csv and saving into separate dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I'm looking to read multiple csv file, and then save them into separate dataframe names.

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(r'blabla/Data', "*.csv" ))

for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
    print('Content:')
    df.pop('Unnamed: 0')
    display(df)
    print
```

When I display(df) within the loop, it displays all three tables in the 3 csv files in that folder. However, when I print df outside the loop, it only gives me the last table that was generated. How do I save each table from the csv file into separate data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you're overwriting the same variable again and again

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(r'blabla/Data', "*.csv" ))

list_of_dfs = []

for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
    print('Content:')
    df.pop('Unnamed: 0')
    display(df)
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

access the individual dataframes with `list_of_dfs[0]`, `list_of_dfs[1]`,...